# Type.IsEnum Property in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core, .net-4.6

I'm trying to code in a `Portable Class Library` using `ASP.NET Core 1.0`, the following instruction:

```
public static void WriteMessage<T>(T value)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        Debug.Print("Is enum")
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Print("Not Is enum")
    }
}
```

But this code does not compile because the compiler says that the property `IsEnum` is non present on Type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum(v=vs.100).aspx) says : "If the current Type represents a type parameter in the definition of a generic type or generic method, this property always returns false." [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e805189-a7e5-4562-a6e4-ae9feff77da7/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fieldtypeisenum-in-metro?forum=winappswithcsharp) may be relevant, too

Answer (score 42):

Some functionality from `Type` was moved to [`TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.reflection.typeinfo#System_Reflection_TypeInfo) in .NET Core.

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I try to use your code but the function GetTypeInfo() is not present on Type. what is wrong?

Comment: `GetTypeInfo()` is an extension method from `IntrospectionExtensions`. Add `using System.Reflection` to your class.

Comment: It's right!!! I forgot the "Using". Thank you Gabriel!! now it works :-)

Comment: This also worked for me. @Karlok mind marking as answer so it can float to the top.